# Customize formatting toolbar in Word for Mac 2016

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, text-formatting

In Word for Mac (2016) I constantly need to highlight with different colors and do other formatting changes. It is very slow to do it using standard options from the formatting toolbar, therefore I tried to look for options for customizing the toolbar, but could not find them. So, anybody does if this is possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Word for Mac Version 15.41, but I imagine the process is similar in  other versions of Word.

You can create macros for different highlight colors with optional keyboard shortcuts.

Open a word document with text in it.

Record Macros:

1. Word > Preferences > View > Show developer tab
2. Select some text in the document.
3. Click on "Record Macro" in developer tab.
4. Name your macro (such as "highlightGreen")
5. Click on "keyboard."
6. Assign a keyboard shortcut (such as cmd+shift+g) and click "ok."
7. Navigate to the Home tab, and select highlight green (which will highlight your selected text).
8. Navigate to Developer tab, click "Stop Recording."

Repeat steps 4 - 8 for each color or format you would like to replicate using a unique keyboard shortcut.

When you select text and use the keyboard shortcut, the formatting from that macro will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can add styles to Word, which are displayed in the styles section of the ribbon.

[image]

1. Open the Styles Pane, then choose New Style.

   [image]
2. Set ‘Style type’ to Character, so that the style applies only to the selection and not the entire paragraph. Set the style preferences you wish to apply for that style, then OK.
3. To apply the style to your current selection, click it in the ribbon.